# Keep getting value of text input

Tags: javascript, html

For the following code:

```
<script>
var text = document.form.text.value;
function test() {
    if(text == "" || text == null){
        alert('No value');
        return false
    }else{
        alert(text);
        }
};
</script>
<form>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text_one"/>
</form><a id="button" onClick="test();">Enter</a><br />
<div id="title_box"></div>
```

Why does it keep alerting 'No Value' even when something has been written? And what would have to be done so that every time a new value is entered, the function gets that new value instead of the old one?

Comment: You are reading the value of the field only once at page load, when it doesn't have a value yet. You have to read the value whenever the user clicks the button.

Answer (score 2):

```
function test() {
    text = document.forms[0].text.value; 
    if(text == "" || text == null){
        alert('No value');
        return false;
    }else{
        alert(text);
        }
};
```

Put text var inside function. Also, notice using of document.forms[0], or give form name/id, as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Because you either have to move the script block after the form closing tag `</form>`, or you have to put the variable code inside the script block in the window.onload

```
window.onload = function(){
   var text = document.form.text.value;
}

function test() {
   if(text == "" || text == null){
        alert('No value');
        return false
     }else{
        alert(text);
      }
 };
```

or

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="text" id="text_one"/>
</form>

<script>
var text = document.form.text.value;
function test() {
    if(text == "" || text == null){
        alert('No value');
        return false
    }else{
        alert(text);
        }
};
</script>

<a id="button" onClick="test();">Enter</a><br />
<div id="title_box"></div>
```

Explanation: The function is correct, but the text variable is initialized before creating the DOM, so it will contain a value of undefined. That's why you have to initialize it after that the DOM is loaded by putting the script code after the form, or by initialize it in the window.onload

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...there are a couple of changes:

```
<script>
    var text = document.forms.myForm.text.value.trim();
    function test() {
        if(text == "" || !text){
            alert('No value');
            return false;
        } else {
            alert(text);
        }
    }
</script>
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="text" id="text_one"/>
</form>
```

In summary:

1. Missing semicolon in your function after return false
2. Give your form an id
3. A null value for text is efficiently detected using trim() AND ! (here as !text)